# How to get childs of child of a parent Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 tables

```
Inventarios -> Localizacoes -> Etiquetas
```

all have one to many relation from left to right

Problem is that i cannot seem to reach Etiquetas

```
// GET: api/Inventarios
public IQueryable<Inventario> GetInventarios()
{
    var inventarios = db.Inventarios.Include(i => i.Localizacoes.Select(l => 
                                                 l.Etiquetas.SelectMany(e => e.Numero)));
    return inventarios;
}
```

and here are the models

```
public class Inventario
{
    public int InventarioID { get; set; }
    public string Colaborador { get; set; }
    public string Armazem { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Localizacao> Localizacoes { get; set; }
}

public class Localizacao
{
    public int LocalizacaoID { get; set; }
    public string Referencia { get; set; }
    public int EtiquetasPorInventariar { get; set; }
    public int EtiquetasInventariadas { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public decimal Precisao { get; set; }

    public int InventarioID { get; set; }
    public Inventario Inventario { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Etiqueta> Etiquetas{ get; set; }
}

public class Etiqueta
{
    public int EtiquetaID { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }

    public int LocalizacaoID { get; set; }
    public Localizacao Localizacao { get; set; }
}
```

this is the exception i get on browser console from api request

> "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties."

Comment: The `SelectMany` doesn't look right, also that fact you are returning an `IQueryable` is suspicious

Comment: Why so? I think it was generated from Controller class, i can't recall though

Comment: it is not clear from your question what exactly you want to get? *All* rows from `Etiqueta`? You don't have any `where` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is you are using `IQueryable` for *OData* support

That aside, there are 2 things i am seeing here that are not looking quite right

The first, is the `SelectMany`it should probably be `Select`

```
var inventarios = db.Inventarios.Include(i => i.Localizacoes.Select(l => 
                                             l.Etiquetas.Select(e => e.Numero)));
```

The second, is you are returning `IQueryable`, i am not really sure this will traverse the object graph.

As a test you could do something like this

```
return inventarios.ToList().AsQuerable();
```

Comment: yes it worked with select, i'm still a beginner using linq though. But either way, it's return json data in correct format and displaing in a table with 2 nested tables